# tkinter if statement when I click no it displays yes

Tags: python, if-statement, tkinter

I decided to mess around with tkinter to show my friends, but I've come across a problem in which at a certain point of the code, when I click no, it still displays what happens when you click yes instead.
Here's the code I've written so far.

```
from tkinter import *
import tkinter.messagebox

root = Tk()

root.title("THE ULTIAMTE TEST OF STRENGTH")

root.geometry('375x50')

topframe = Frame(root)
topframe.pack(side=TOP)
bottomframe = Frame(root)
bottomframe.pack(side=BOTTOM)

def butt1(event):
tkinter.messagebox.showinfo("Narrator: WHAT HAVE YOU DONE", "Prepare your soul for the hardest question ever")

answer = tkinter.messagebox.askquestion("Mother:", "Just got back home from work. Have you cleaned your room?")

if answer == 'yes':
    tkinter.messagebox.showinfo("Mother:", "Wow, you actually did something useful for once.")

    tkinter.messagebox.askquestion("Mother:", "WAIT, have you done the dishes yet? ")

    if answer == 'yes':
        tkinter.messagebox.showinfo("Mother:", "I'm Surprised. You've never been this productive in your entire life. Good job.")
        tkinter.messagebox.askquestion("Mother:", "WAIT ANOTHER MINUTE YOU FRAGILE CHILD. Have you done your laundry? ")

        if answer == 'yes':
            tkinter.messagebox.showinfo("Mother:", "Oh my, what a miracle! I can't believe you actually did what you were supposed to do!")
            tkinter.messagebox.showinfo("Mother:", "I'm still gonna whoop ya")
            tkinter.messagebox.showinfo("Narrator:", "You got whooped.")

        if answer == 'no':
            tkinter.messagebox.showinfo("Mother:", "Oh my goodness you trashcan of a child, if you don't do yo laundry within the next 3 seconds I'm shoving all ya clothes down ya throat, YA HEAR ME?")

            tkinter.messagebox.showinfo("Narrator:", "It's been 3 seconds.")

    if answer == 'no':
        tkinter.messagebox.showinfo("Mother:", "Of course you haven't. There's only so much you can do before you become useless again.")

        tkinter.messagebox.askquestion("Mother:", "Last Question. Have you done your laundry?")

        if answer == 'yes':
            tkinter.messagebox.showinfo("Mother:", "Fair enough, but you still have to do the dishes or else you gettin'' the greatest whoopin of yo life.")

            tkinter.messagebox.showinfo("Narrator:", "Just do yo dang dishes")

        if answer == 'no':
            tkinter.messagebox.showinfo("Mother:", "Oh my goodness you trashcan of a child, if you don't do yo laundry within the next 3 seconds I'm shoving all ya clothes down ya throat, YA HEAR ME?")

            tkinter.messagebox.showinfo("Narrator:", "It's been 3 seconds.")


if answer == 'no':
    tkinter.messagebox.showinfo("Mother:", "YOU'RE SUCH A USELESS CHILD THERE'S NO POINT IN EVEN RAISING YOU AT THIS POINT")

    tkinter.messagebox.askquestion("Mother:", "Have you at least done the dishes?")

def butt2(event):
tkinter.messagebox.showinfo("WHAT HAVE YOU DONE", "Prepare your soul for the hardest question ever")

answer = tkinter.messagebox.askquestion("Mother:", "Just got back home from work. Have you cleaned your room?")

if answer == 'yes':
    tkinter.messagebox.showinfo("Mother:", "Wow, you actually did something useful for once.")

    tkinter.messagebox.askquestion("Mother:", "WAIT, have you done the dishes yet? ")

if answer == 'no':
    tkinter.messagebox.showinfo("Mother:", "YOU'RE SUCH A USELESS CHILD THERE'S NO POINT IN EVEN RAISING YOU AT THIS POINT")

    tkinter.messagebox.askquestion("Mother:", "Have you at least done the dishes?")

button_1 = Button(root, text="BEWARE OF THIS BUTTON", bg = 'black', fg='red')
button_1.bind("<Button-1>", butt1)
button_1.pack(fill=X)

button_2 = Button(root, text="DON'T BE AWARE OF THIS BUTTON", bg='yellow', fg='green')
button_2.bind("<Button-2>", butt2)
button_2.pack(fill=X)

button_1.pack(side=TOP)
button_2.pack(side=BOTTOM)
root.mainloop()
```

Also another thing is that when I click the second button, nothing happens at all.

Comment: You only assign the result of `.askquestion()` to a variable in a couple of places.  All of the other times, the user's answer is completely ignored.  Also, the normal way of assigning a function to a Tkinter Button is via the `command=` option when creating the button, not an event binding.

Comment: Please try simplifying your code a bit first.  Nested if statements are often poor form, especially when they're checking the same variable.

Also, if x:
    do_something();
elif y:
    do_something_else();

 is not necessarily the same as

if x:
    do_something();
if y:
    do_something_else();

 Be careful, because the computer isn't smart enough to guess what you mean.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your butt1() function, you have this line once towards the top:

```
answer = tkinter.messagebox.askquestion(...)
```

But, thereafter you are not assigning new values from the askquestion() function to the "answer" variable. That's why once you said yes, it's going to be yes for the rest of the function. So, you just need to add "answer = " in front of the rest of the askquestion() lines.

**EDITED** to address second question:

For the second button not responding, it's due to your binding. Change this line:

```
button_2.bind("<Button-2>", butt2)
```

Change Button-2 to Button-1 and that should work. Button-1 is for left click. Button-2 is middle click. More info in the [documentation here](http://effbot.org/tkinterbook/tkinter-events-and-bindings.htm).

Comment: Holy cow that completely solved the problem. Thank you!